# Why not using a typedef for a struct in C?

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I'm studying an application in C for ARM low-powered devices, I have this piece of code in the first place

```
struct state {
    float position;
    int dummy;
};
```

notice how this struct does not define a new type, I also have noticed that later in the code this struct is used like this

```
struct state mystate;
```

which is something odd and not convenient to me, not flexible and with 1 extra useless keyword that i can easily avoid just using `typedef` for the struct in the first place.

This is a struct that is vital for the business logic of this application and is also used a lot in the source code.

There is a particular reason for not using `typedef` with a struct that in the end is used as a type?

Comment: This really has nothing to do with power or even ARM. It's a C syntax convention.

Comment: Well, if typing `struct` is too much of a chore, you can `typedef` it yourself still.

Comment: Typedefs fill up the namespace. Programmers have a "mental namespace" of about 7 identifiers. Keywords don't count. For the human reader "struct" is a 0-byte token.

Comment: @DanielFischer yes, but why using extra code even if it's just 1 word each line?

Comment: Because the `struct` keyword tells the reader something about the type.

Comment: Concur with wildplasser.  Typedef types are bad noise.

Comment: typedefs will cause your "mental desk" to be clobbered with typedefs.

Comment: I use typedef for structs like this because I think the code is more readable that way.

Comment: Ken: I think you are too much preoccupied with your typing effort. Try to consider the reading effort needed to read (and understand!) your code. Have you ever tried to read the code you wrote yourself, ten years ago?

Comment: @wildplasser in the past days i have only coded in C++ and honestly i have never ever see this kind of approach in C for the struct. So basically i probably expected a layer of abstraction that i have always used and this is new to me. I get what the application does, my problem, and the focus of this question, is about this way of treat structs.

Comment: Well: C and C++ are different languages. They attract different people. Could be a cultural thing (men with beards and such) ... <insert lbt quote here>

Comment: First, this is a duplicate question. Second, it's a religious issue. The people who say that typedef for struct is bad have very strongly held but poorly reasoned explanations. If you think their explanations hold water but rationally want to avoid the `struct` noise anyway, then code in C++, which makes the `typedef` (and therefore `struct`) superfluous.

Comment: And nothing stops you to declare `typedef struct state state` making the link between the tag namespace and the typedef namespace (in C++ it's already in the language). That is even a convenient way of doing encapsulation in C. Have the typedef in the header and the implementation of the structure in a c file.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I consider typedef harmful.  I think it almost invariably mis-used.  In my opinion, it is useful and only useful when the underlying type is FULLY abstracted - e.g. ALL manipulation is through functions.  Otherwise, the underlying type is not abstracted - the user still has to know what it is, to make sense of the code - all that has happened is that code readabiliy has been impaired, where the type namespace has been without gain (for the type is not properly abstracted) extended.

In my view, almost all use of typedef lacks understanding of the problems it brings and how it ought to be used.

Comment: i just read in this discussion that typedefs are just labels for abstraction, in what way they can be problematic?

Comment: Abstraction is only abstraction if there is abstraction.  Consider.  Say you typedef an integer.  You then later use the addition operator.  *You have just broken abstraction*.  The user HAS to know the underlying type or he cannot understand the code - and so he now has to remember another type.  This failure is pervasive.  I've seen code bases which typedef a few dozen types, and then break abstraction - nightmare.  The only true abstraction with typedef is when ALL operations occur through function calls; the user NEVER has to know the underlying type.

Comment: i think i now understand the core issue about this, thanks.

Comment: "Say you typedef an integer" -- non sequitur; the question was about typedef for structs. In the case of structs it's just a matter of syntax, not breaking of abstractions. @Ken the core issue is that it's a religiously held opinion.

Comment: @Jim: I think calling it a religious issue is a blind. In fact, it is not - there is a clear set of advantages, disadvantages and mis-uses. The integer example illustrates the mis-use of violating abstraction which is the primary failing of typedefs; so that's one thing. The use of typedefs for structs, as far as I can see, has no justification. The struct already has a type, so a typedef is not required for that; and an incomplete type provides abstraction. The and the only effect of a typedef for a struct is to increase the logical complexity of the code.

Comment: 'I think calling it a religious issue is a blind' -- you're wrong, and that's ad hominem. 'so that's one thing' -- an irrelevant thing to the OP's question, as I said. 'The use of typedefs for structs, as far as I can see, has no justification' -- it has an obvious justification stated by the OP ... it avoids the need for the struct noise word. 'the only effect of a typedef for a struct is to increase the logical complexity of the code' -- it does no such thing; it adds two tokens to the code while allowing removing many others, and has no effect on the logic. My final word on this.

Comment: No, the idea to abstract types behind typedefs is to __introduce__ semantics in the program. A `size_t`, `off_t` or even `time_t`are typedefed base types, but they introduce a higher level meaning in a program. This increases (often significantly) the readability of a program.

Answer (score 6):

A little detail that wasn't mentioned here, from the C standard.

> 6.7.7.3 [...] A typedef declaration does not introduce a new type, only a synonym for the type so specified.

You can use it to abstract some details away, though when someone goes to the extreme of only allowing function calls, I wonder how they ever allocate memory where a `size_t` and the leaking knowledge that it is an unsigned int type are necessary.

Given that it is only an alias, I don't have any problems with using typedef for shortcuts also, e.g. to omit an additional keyword that is necessary everywhere. I don't like repeated boilerplate code, and hiding it away makes code shorter. You should just be a bit careful that clarity and readability are not impacted, so I also prefer to consistently keep the namespaces clean. I find this to be bad:

```
typedef struct state {
    float position;
    int dummy;
} state;
```

and prefer something like this instead:

```
typedef struct s_state {
    float position;
    int dummy;
} t_state;
```

Comment: You don't need to name the struct at all ... `typedef struct { float position; int dummy; } State;` ... so you just add one token to your struct declarations and remove a token from every use of the type. This is obviously the sensible thing to do and is purely a matter of syntax, and no valid objection has been raised. (Objections to some other typedefs may be valid but aren't relevant to the OP's question about struct.)

Answer (score 5):

This is mostly for clarity. In practice it is mostly understood that if you have to use the struct keyword you should manipulate the internal data yourself. When structs are typedef'd it's to hide the actual type and manipulation should be done by functions. This is a convention that is not always followed and others just leave the struct keyword in to distinguish it from opaque types.

Comment: Incomplete types can also be used as opaque types. At no additional cost (and without revealing the internals)

Comment: @wildplasser: exactly.  I do *not* like typdefs.  They are and only are useful when the underlying type is FULLY abstracted, e.g. operated on by and only by functions - and that almost never, ever happens.  As far as I can see, people use typdef because they have seen other using it, without understanding its problems or how it should be used.

Comment: I think we agree. Function pointers are the obvious example. But that is caused mostly by the need for mental sanity;-)

Comment: Typedef makes sense for things like lock types (spinlock_t), pthread (pthread_t), etc... when ALL manipulation is done via API and you essentially need a "handle" to the actual data. Also the question was mainly about structs and typedef.

Answer (score 4):

Using `typedef` or not is personal preference. Personally, I only use `typedef` for complex pointer types or function pointers.

When you declare a struct, you also declare a type along with it, namely `struct structName`. All typedef does is allows you to take out the `struct` part of the definition in this scenario, and isn't necessary. This has no relation to low power devices at all.